# Filename invalid Filezilla localhost

Tags: php, ftp

I have a problem with the localhost server from FileZilla. I have settings for the shared folder and credentials. [FileZilla settings *IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdGMf.png)

```
class FtpConfig 
{
public const SERVER = '127.0.0.1';
public const USER = 'root';
public const PASSWORD = 'root';
public const TARGET_DIR = 'C:/Users/B4UTR3N/Desktop/images/';
public const DESTINATION_DIR = './images/';
}

public static function upload($name): string
{
    $conn = ftp_connect(FtpConfig::SERVER);

    $uploadFile = FtpConfig::TARGET_DIR . basename($_FILES[$name]['name']);
    $destinationPath = FtpConfig::DESTINATION_DIR . basename($_FILES[$name]['name']);
    $uploadFileFTP = $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'];

    ftp_login($conn, FtpConfig::USER, FtpConfig::PASSWORD);
    ftp_put($conn, $uploadFile, $uploadFileFTP, FTP_BINARY) or die('Error with upload file on server' . PHP_EOL); // todo MS DIE_DELETE;

    return $destinationPath;
}
```

LOG:

```
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> USER root
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 331 Password required for root
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> PASS ****
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> 230 Logged on
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> TYPE I
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> 200 Type set to I
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> PORT 127,0,0,1,222,74
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> 200 Port command successful
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> STOR C:/Users/B4UTR3N/Desktop/images/aboutUs.png
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> 550 Filename invalid
(000025)10.06.2020 17:29:05 - root (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't send FTP commands that contain paths starting with `C:/`. Those are local paths from your hard disk drive. Paths in network services are "virtual" and local to that service and server.

That paths comes from the second argument for [ftp_put()](https://php.net/ftp_put), which is meant to be:

> The remote file path.

However you feed it with:

```
public const TARGET_DIR = 'C:/Users/B4UTR3N/Desktop/images/';
```

If unsure of remote paths, just install FileZilla client and have a look with your own eyes.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the virtual path that you see in the *Aliases* column of the *Shared folders* FileZilla server settings.

It's not visible on your screenshot, but it  will be like:

```
public const TARGET_DIR = '/images/';
```